# Why is JOptionPane not accepting this string?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am having issues with String msg3 being displayed in my JOptionPane. When run I get a "String cannot be converted to int" error. If the 3 different strings are separated into their own panes the program will run, however, I need them all to be in the same one. Thank you for any advice/ help in advance.

```
        //add all of the expenses together
        double total = airfare1 + carRent1 + parking1 + reg1 + (lodge1 * numberOfDays1) + (meals * numberOfDays1);
        String msg1;


        msg1 = String.format("Total cost: $%,.2f\n Allowed expenses: $%,.2f\n", total);



        //Calculate the allowable reinbusement
        double allow = airfare1 + carRent1 + ( pfees * numberOfDays1) + reg1 + (lfees * numberOfDays1) + (meals * numberOfDays1);
        String msg2;

        msg2 = String.format("Allowed expenses: $%,.2f\n", allow);



        //calculates the total amount to be paid back
        double pback = total - allow;
        String msg3;

        msg3 = String.format("Amount to be paid back: $%,.2f\n", pback);



        //display the totals using joptionpane
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg1,msg2,msg3);
```

Comment: You have three text strings (`msg1`, `msg2` and `msg3`), and you are passing them as separate arguments to the `showMessageDialog` method. It doesn't work like that. I assume you want the strings to be concatenated. Try `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg1 + msg2 + msg3)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[See the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon))

The argument that you passed msg3 is String, but method accepts integer. There is no direct conversion from **String** to **int**.